# Specflow/Selenium Searching through a table element by row and column

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am currently having an issue which is when I am trying to search through a table on a webpage I'm not quite sure how to search for a specific row and column.

I am using page locators to find the page elements so i am able to find the table but I just dont know how to search through the table.

I know in Watir you would do "table_element[row][column]" is it the same sort of principle with specflow, if you could give me an example it would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

use this link to understand about handling webtables

http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/2014/06/how-to-handle-dynamic-web-table-in.html